# "Read only" JSLint Error

Tags: javascript, jslint

I'm trying to set up google maps geolocation and and JSLint keeps saying "Read only." for this code:

```
function geolocationSuccess(position) {
    // Turn the geolocation position into a LatLng object.
    location = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);

    // Map that point.
    map.setCenter(location);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Maybe it's complaining about you setting `window.location`.

Comment: @Jordan yes why is it JSLint saying that and how do I fix it

Comment: Similar question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705035/javascript-jslint-throws-read-only

Comment: @Srikanth so I would write the same thing? /*global arrayContainer:true*/

Comment: @JakeScervino it might be worth it to learn how JSLint works and [how those `/* global` comments work](http://www.jslint.com/help.html#global), so that you don't have to ask a question every time you run into another JSLint error...

Comment: I know im sorry, Im reading an HTML5 book but I didnt realize there would be PHP and javascript involved.... I was planning on reading some javascript and PHP books later on but I just wanted to know html5

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing `var location` instead of `location`? See below

```
function geolocationSuccess(position) {
  // Turn the geolocation position into a LatLng object.
  var location = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);

  // Map that point.
  map.setCenter(location);
}
```

It seems that JSLint is complaining about a global variable that cannot be assigned. `var location` would make `location` into a local variable instead of a global one.

Comment: That worked thank you! but it doesnt show `var` before `location` in the example in the book...

Comment: Well... if it has location defined as `var location` OUTSIDE of `geolocationSuccess` function (but in the same file), then INSIDE the function you CAN have just location (without the var).

Comment: I already tried that and it still gave me the same error... :/